# How to add a component like a button, programmatically from the java code instead of adding it from XML?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I want to add a button programmatically from the java code rather than adding it from the XML file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First step is to instantiate button inside onStart(), later add the instantiated button to the ComponentContainer or setUIContent();

```java
 @Override
    protected void onStart(Intent intent) {
        super.onStart(intent);
        Button button = new Button(MainAbilitySlice.this);
        setUIContent(button);
    }
```